# AttributeError: type object 'CustomUser' has no attribute 'REQUIRED_FIELDS'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a Custom User model in Django. I am getting error which is

> if not isinstance(cls.REQUIRED_FIELDS, (list, tuple)): AttributeError:
> type object 'CustomUser' has no attribute 'REQUIRED_FIELDS'

I have added my CustomUser model at settings.py like below.

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "Pollapp.CustomUser"
```

Also here is my model.py

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """
    Custom user model manager where email is the unique identifiers
    for authentication instead of usernames.
    """
    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('The Email must be set'))
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password.
        """
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_staff=True.'))
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.'))
        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

Here is my serializers.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('__all__')


class UserSerializerWithToken(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    token = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

    def get_token(self, obj):
        jwt_payload_handler = api_settings.JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER
        jwt_encode_handler = api_settings.JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER

        payload = jwt_payload_handler(obj)
        token = jwt_encode_handler(payload)
        return token

    def create(self, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop('password', None)
        instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
        if password is not None:
            instance.set_password(password)
        instance.save()
        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('token', 'email', 'password')

class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True, validators=[validate_password])
    password2 = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)
    email = serializers.EmailField(allow_blank=False)

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email', 'password', 'password2')
    def validate(self, attrs):
        if attrs['password'] != attrs['password2']:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({"password": "Password fields didn't match."})

        return attrs

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = CustomUser.objects.create(
            email=validated_data['email'],
        )
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()

        return user
```

Comment: I tried deleting and recreating the database. it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

By removing `AUTH_USER_MODEL = "Pollapp.CustomUser"` in `setings.py` it worked for me.

Comment: Now, I am getting another error. 'CustomUser() got an unexpected keyword argument 'email'.     My json format is like { email: 'email@gmail.com', password:'pswrd123', password2:'pswrd123'